# Elementor. Вставка кода в текстовое поле

Tags: wordpress-плагины, elementor

Всем привет! Работаю с Elementor. Бесплатная версия. Обновлял недавно до последней версии. Еще есть старая, на другом сайте.

Мне в аккордеон надо засунуть небольшой код на исполнение. Всегда делал так. Заходил в Содержимое, переключал поле с Визуального на Текст и писал нужный мне код (см. пример).

Сейчас по этой схеме заполнял аккордеон и у меня ни в какую не хочет копировать данные. Причем, на старой версии Elementor такая же проблема. С новой версией Elementora я проверил еще на мобильном, чтобы убедиться, что это не настройки браузера. Ни в какую не работает.

После этого создал секцию с виджетом <HTML-код>. Код рабочий. На браузерах и на мобильных выполняется.

Начну с простого. Может что-то сделано не так и можно таки затолкать этот код в аккордеон, чтобы он работал?

```
<fieldset>
        <legend>Какая сегодня погода</legend>
        <input id="myInput" type="text" value="отличная погода" />
      
        <button onclick="myFunction()">Поприветствовать мир</button>
      
        <script>
          function myFunction() {
            var copyText = document.getElementById("myInput");
            copyText.select();
            document.execCommand("copy");
            alert("Вы сказали Васе: " + copyText.value + " сэр");
          }
        </script>
      </fieldset>
```